# How can i disable any android app such that it cannot be opened until i change/press some button in app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-package-managers, android-securityexception

I am trying to build a parental control app. So now i want to disable or lock app (like Whatsapp, Facebook, etc). I have tried using `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()`. But it is throwing `java.lang.SercurityException`.

**So how can I make a parental control app such that I can disable any app I want without root**.

my code is

```
 pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(temp.activityInfo.packageName,
                        temp.activityInfo.name+".class"),
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

my error was this

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=11537, uid=10067, package uid=10029

Comment: As a suggestion you can Add conditions in your splash screen activity to check if the app is unlocked by parent or not, you can save lock/unlock detail on a server

Comment: You describe a parenting control, I read ransomware (not saying this is your idea, just that this could be use as it) This would be a reason why this might not be possible to restrict the access of any app.

Answer (score 0):

You must add below permissions to manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

but , these permissions are for System apps and you can not use. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can not write a app to lock or close another app.this is a policy in Google.
for lock a app you must check running apps repeatedly, if specific app is open,then show a activity over that.

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
{
    String topActivity = getFrontApp();

    if(topActivity.isEmpty())
    {
        threadSleep(500);
        continue;
    }


    if(topActivity.equals("lockApp"))
    {
        showLockActivity();
    }

    threadSleep(500);
}

// for Api21+ need permission
    public static String getFrontApp()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            UsageStatsManager usageManager = SystemMaster.getUsageStatsManager();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> localList = usageManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, now - 900_000L, now);
            String str = "";

            if (localList != null)
            {
                SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();

                for(UsageStats usageStats : localList)
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);

                if(!mySortedMap.isEmpty())
                    str =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }

            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    }
```

above code is very simple , for real app must write more.